# Qt: make a browser which can download

Tags: qt, http, qtwebkit

I am making a browser in qt and i wanted to know how to make it download/save files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple program which fetches files from a url string, look at the "HTTP Example"

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use QNetworkAccessManager. With Qt Webkit Bridge.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html